# how we can delete duplicate entries from Array List

Tags: java

How we can delete duplicate entries from StudentList object. Here we can identify student is duplicate or not if more according to entry sequence.

```
class Student
{
  String name;
  long phone;
  String address;
  boolean isActive;
  Student(String name, long phone, String address, boolean isActive)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.address = address;
    this.isActive = isActive;
  }
}
```

this is execution class.

```
class CollegeMgmt
{
  public static void main(String s[])
  {
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Student s1 = new Student("devid", 9898989898L, "Stainford d23", true);
    studentList.add(s1);
    Student s2 = new Student("sames", 9895555598L, "Stainford d23", true);
    studentList.add(s2);
    Student s3 = new Student("devid", 9898989898L, "Stainford d23", false);
    studentList.add(s3);
    Student s4 = new Student("devid", 9898989898L, "Stainford d23", false);
    studentList.add(s4);
    Student s5 = new Student("devid", 9898989898L, "Stainford d23", true);
    studentList.add(s5);
  }
}
```

I want to know which approach will be best to delete all duplicate entries from studentList.
duplicate is here if two or more entry are same as

```
    Student s3 = new Student("devid", 9898989898L, "Stainford d23", false);
    studentList.add(s1);
    Student s4 = new Student("devid", 9898989898L, "Stainford d23", false);
    studentList.add(s1);
```

this is on the behalf of isActive bit, if in our list continues same bit we are setting then that object is need to delete. there s4 object should be remove no other object should be remove.

Comment: over there they are showing removing duplicate items for string objects and that way can not be applied to above type of problems. Using inner and outer loop we can delete. But i want to know that is there any other way?

Comment: @VinaySharma This sounds pretty much like you ask other people to do your homework. Do you really think you learn more from not even trying to solve your assignments yourself?

Comment: No this is not right, i have done it already but i think complexity is to much that is O(2n) so i want to know best solution for such type of problems.

Comment: Jägermeister would you like to say some thing on above problem. I have resolve this problem by using two loops. Are you having other solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably start by overriding `Object.equals` in `Student` (by testing the fields that determine *equality*). Next, use a `Set` which will prevent duplicates (a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), for example, preserves insertion order).

Comment: here two properties combine and define that student is duplicate or not, name and his phone number

Comment: @VinaySharma Okay, then first you write a equals method to test the `name` and `phone number`.

Comment: thank you sir, but can you again look into above problem, sorry i have done some modifications. thank you for your reply

Comment: @VinaySharma I recommended you override `equals`. I looked. You still haven't.

Answer (score 2):

Use Set interface to avoid duplicate values. [The Set Interface](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm)

[Example of Duplicate value](http://www.quizover.com/question/how-the-set-collection-allows-no-duplicates-in-java)